# VirtualBox 7.0 fails to start its module after install

Tags: fedora, virtualbox

What does all of this mean, and how can I get it to work?

```
Running transaction
  Preparing        :                                                                                                                              1/1 
  Installing       : qt5-qttools-libs-help-5.15.8-1.fc36.x86_64                                                                                   1/2 
  Running scriptlet: VirtualBox-7.0-7.0.6_155176_fedora36-1.x86_64                                                                                2/2 
  Installing       : VirtualBox-7.0-7.0.6_155176_fedora36-1.x86_64                                                                                2/2 
  Running scriptlet: VirtualBox-7.0-7.0.6_155176_fedora36-1.x86_64                                                                                2/2 

Creating group 'vboxusers'. VM users must be member of that group!

vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.

  Verifying        : qt5-qttools-libs-help-5.15.8-1.fc36.x86_64                                                                                   1/2 
  Verifying        : VirtualBox-7.0-7.0.6_155176_fedora36-1.x86_64                                                                                2/2 

Installed:
  VirtualBox-7.0-7.0.6_155176_fedora36-1.x86_64                               qt5-qttools-libs-help-5.15.8-1.fc36.x86_64                              

Complete!

[root@fedora Downloads]# modprobe -v vboxdrv
insmod /lib/modules/6.2.14-100.fc36.x86_64/misc/vboxdrv.ko 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Exec format error
```

Comment: *If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load them.* Or simply disable Secure Boot.

Comment: @ChanganAuto ... do the right thing and sign your modules. What you're saying, at least in a business computer context, is similar to "*your car might be beeping if you don't put on your seatbelt. To stop the beeping, put on a seatbelt*. Or simply smash the beeping speaker with a hammer."

Comment: @ChanganAuto furthermore, in this case, the error points out it's probably a version mismatch. The kernel module was built for a different kernel. So you're advising to remove a security feature without any functional benefit :(

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, it's probably a version mismatch. And I do use Secure Boot per policy but often recommend others to disable it mostly to troubleshoot things like this or in gaming machines to avoid the nuisance with Nvidia drivers. Due to its nature and usage, gaming oriented PCs do not benefit that much if at all from Secure Boot.

Comment: fair point! That's true.